# Como fazer duas chamadas do Retrofit em cadeia com RxJava?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, kotlin, rxjava

Faço uma chamada para recuperar alguns dados e a segunda chamada - que deveria ser feita dentro da primeira - utiliza um dos campos da chamada anterior.

```
val restApi = retrofit.create(RestAPI::class.java)
testAPI.searchDoc("language", "title_query")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { p0 ->
             /** É aqui onde eu quero recuperar os dados de p0 e com eles fazer 
                 a segunda chamada. **/
            }
        }
```

**Como que eu utilizo um dos campos da primeira chamada para fazer a segunda?** Estou utilizando Kotlin e trabalhando com o RxJava.

**Pergunta resumida:** Como eu utilizo os dados recuperados na primeira chamada para fazer a segunda dentro do RxAndroid?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que no seu caso é melhor fazer dentro da *chain*, e não no subscribe. Utilize o operador [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html):

```
val restApi = retrofit.create(RestAPI::class.java)
restApi.searchDoc("language", "title_query")
    .flatMap { restApi.doSomethingWithDoc(it.field) }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { p0 ->

    }
```

Se você precisa do valor original, pode usar a função mapeadora e retornar um Pair (ou qualquer outra coisa):

```
restApi.searchDoc("language", "title_query")
    .flatMap({ restApi.doSomethingWithDoc(it.field) }, { doc, smt -> Pair(doc, smt) }, false)
    .subscribe { pair ->
    }
```